# tensorboard not rendering when I use local runtime for colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, local, tensorboard

I am connecting to local run time in Google colab. I tried loading tensorboard. It does not give any error but I can only see a blank space. It works fine if I connect to hosted runtime in colab.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@today.rafi/tensorboard-in-google-colab-bd49fa554f9b) and [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb) to setup tensorboard in Google Colab.

In some cases, the logdir you're pointing tensorboard to probably does not exist, Please check and make sure you are pointing to correct log directory. Thank you!